# Can incorrect hyphenation be fixed?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Microsoft Word 16.16.4 for Mac.  I notice that when I let Word hyphenate automatically, it gets the word "although" wrong, hyphenating it as alt-hough.

Does Word have a dictionary that tells it where the hyphens belong for each word it knows about?  If so, is there a way to edit or add to this dictionary?

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/using_manual_hyphenation.html

Word isn't known as a decent writer's tool and its lack of a hyphenation dictionary is one of the reasons.

Comment: @Ring Thanks.  I already figured out how to fix it manually, but it's painful, and I'd have to do it every time.  But the information that there's no dictionary is helpful.  I'm  sure it's not possible to get every word correct even with a dictionary, but getting a very common word like "although" wrong just looks really bad--they really should have special-cased that one.

Comment: Isn't it, though? If you turn on automatic again, it doesn't seem to remember your manual changes, either. I understand the issue. I'm a long time FrameMaker user and sincerely hate Microsoft's lack of notice when one asks for features useful to writers. I could go on and on... Word is fine for short memos, but forget complex lists or any serious typographic considerations. Anyway, I'm glad I could help.